# IDEA View Tool Buttons/Windows per editor window

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IDEA on multiple monitors. I drag tabs off my "main" editor window and get a new window that I can put on the other monitor. On this second window I would like to also have all the tool windows like Structure, Maven Projects, etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for this feature request:

- [IDEA-171078](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171078) [Feature] add tool window on detached editor frames

Comment: Voted and commented. Thanks.